# Bother to report errors in books to authors?

Tags: physical-books

Recently I read a couple of books with some of the following mistakes:

- Spelling
- Phrasing
- Scientific errors in equations
- Word duplications
- Other typography errors: formatting, missing colors, etc.

Should I bother reporting this to the authors? I do not want to be unpolite but some errors are severe and make the reading hard to understand. Would it matter anyway? Some books are in 3rd/4th edition and still contain these kind of mistakes.

Comment: If anything you would probably want to notify the publisher as the error may have been on their end, especially when you get into typography errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to say how the author or the publisher will respond to the reported errors. There are publishers that maintain a list of errata online, including errata reported by readers. See for example the list of [errata for *Introduction to Machine Learning with Python*, published by O'Reilly Media](https://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9781449369415).

As an anecdote, I can tell you the story of a colleague's brother, who worked through a textbook, listing all the errors, including suggestions for improvement, and sent that list to the publisher. As a reward, the publisher later sent him the next edition of the book free of charge.

I don't know to what extent this also applies to publishers of literary works.

Comment: It's actually a textbook in the field of Computer Science.

Comment: If it's a textbook and the author is a professor, you may be able to contact them directly. In other cases, you need to contact the publisher, which is not always easy. (Some publishers don't make that easy.) I added the comment about literary works because this is, after all, a site that focuses on literature.

Comment: yes I know. Didn't find a better place to ask this question. It will be tedious to list now the errors as I forgot the pages of course but there have been tremendous number of issues.

Answer (score 2):

Most authors who I have contacted to report errors have been grateful that someone cared enough to read their book closely enough to note the errors, although some have declined to issue a correction.

One thing to note is that if this is an electronic book on Kindle, and you have any care for the author, **do not report the book on Amazon**. That triggers an automatic process which can lock a book away for sales for weeks, and according to some authors, leaves a black mark on their record which impacts their ability to sell other books, even if they immediately make and submit a correction.